# Responsive Effect

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

This is more of a directional question.

Is there a way to run a responsive elements, say a responsive menu, inside a non-responsive website - that is, a website in which there can be no viewport tag. Alternatively, is there a recommended approach to achieving the same effect where a menu alone would be properly proportioned for mobile screen sizes.

Comment: why can't you use viewports?

Answer (score 0):

The way responsive sites work is by using Media Queries, and generally a grid system.

What you simply need to do is a media query that will affect only the menu, you don't need to implement or use a whole grid system.

For more info read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

**EDIT**

Inside your media query, you'll be able to specify styles for the html elements that you need to resize accordingly. Be sure to put these in the bottom of your document so that, when they are matched, they overwrite the default styles.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by doing this, but i think what you are looking for is more a Fluid Layout than a Responsive Layout.

Comment: Thanks. But media queries require a viewport meta tag. This is for a situation in which no viewport meta tag can be used.

Comment: right, well if you can't use a viewport i'd say go for a fluid layout